# How to get the sum from comma separated string in angular2 or typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular2 and typescript.I am very new to this.
I have one string where values are separated by comma.

selected: 5000,5000,2500.00

I want to get the sum of these values.
I am not getting how to write code for this in angular2 or typescript.

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

as easy as this :

```js
let selected = "5000,5000,2500.00";
let sum = selected.split(",").reduce((prev,next)=>prev+(+next),0);
console.log(sum)
```

1. `selected.split(",")` split the string into an array of strings :`["5000", "5000", "2500.00"]` [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
2. `.reduce()` : iterate over that array and output a single value computed from the items it contains. The `(+next)` part of the `(pev,next)=>prev+(+next)` callback allows to cast the `next` value to a number instead of a string.
   [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain Javascript:

```js
var string = "5000,5000,2500.00";
var nums = string.split(",");
var sum = 0;

nums.forEach(function (number) {
    sum += parseFloat(number);
});

console.log(sum);
```

Note: If you're using ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), you can replace the function in forEach with an arrow function for a more concise representation:

```
nums.forEach(number => sum += parseFloat(number));
```